# Installing and configuring xen with out virtmanager and GUI

Tags: virtualization, xen, ubuntu-12.04

Is there any alternative to configure and install many vms and manage them on a remote machine running on ubuntu 12.04  using XEN.we have to configure vm on a remote machine through ssh.can it be done with out GUI??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure. There are many ways to do this.

- Clone an existing image (with dd, cp or rsync)
- run the full installation of the DomU in text-mode
- use `xm console` to connect to the text-console

But why do you want to do this without gui?
You can log into your Dom0 with `ssh -X` and then start `virt-manager`.

Comment: Thanks alot for your suggestion..Based on ur suggestion I tried X11 forwarding(ssh -x) but i am getting a lot of error while doing it as mentioned here can u help me please,, http://serverfault.com/questions/392616/managing-xen-through-virt-manager-on-ubuntu-12-04

Comment: @user113505 in that case you will be propably faster with mxrx-answer - go for `virt-install`. I had no clue that virt-manager does not work on Ubuntu...

Answer (score 0):

Yes - you can use virt-install.  Check out http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/intrepid/man1/virt-install.1.html - which both explains the command and provides some handy examples.